# Angular route redirectTo param triggers Error: Uncaught (in promise)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

Here is my `route` code -

```
{ path: 'search',
  children: [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/products', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: ':cat_id/:query', component: SearchComponent }
  ]
},
{ path: 'products',
  children: [
  { path: '', component: ProductsComponent },
  { path: 'compare', component: ProductComparePageComponent },
  { path: ':cat', component: CategoryComponent },
  ]
},
```

So when I set my URL to `/search` it can redirect me to `/products` URL. But I get following error in Angular SSR -

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error
>       at resolvePromise (.../dist/server.js:1002:31)
>       at resolvePromise (.../dist/server.js:959:17)

Comment: can you try `/search` as well ?

Comment: Sorry, that was `/search`. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I have given an example for route constant with child routes, hope it will help you.

```
const crisisCenterRoutes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'crisis-center',
  component: CrisisCenterComponent,
  children: [
   {
    path: '',
    component: CrisisListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: CrisisDetailComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: CrisisCenterHomeComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]}
];
```

According to your code,

```
{ path: 'search',
  component: 'SomeComponent,
  children: [
   { path: '', redirectTo: '/products', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: ':cat_id/:query', component: SearchComponent }
  ]
},
{ path: 'products',
 component: 'AnotherComponent',
 children: [
  { path: '', component: ProductsComponent },
  { path: 'compare', component: ProductComparePageComponent },
  { path: ':cat', component: CategoryComponent },
  ]
},
```

Comment: can you add `pathMatch: 'prefix'` and remove  `pathMatch: 'full'`from child route ?

Comment: tryied your issue in already existing [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-child-routes?file=app%2Fapp-routing.module.ts) and added `{ path: '', redirectTo: '/about', pathMatch: 'full' }` inside admin route as a child, but i worked as expected. when I type `/admin` it redirected to `/about`. please add the given route to that project and check.